# Calculating Distance using Google maps API & passing value between javascript and C#

Tags: google-maps-api-3, distance

I am using Google maps API for the first time hence facing few difficulties and need help.
I have a requirement to find distance between few points and keep them saved for later use.
Below is the exact scenario and problem i am facing.

I am using Latitude, longitude data that i have to find distance.

**Scenario:**

- Find distance between point A & point 1,2,3.
- Find distance between point B & point 1,2,3.
- Find distance between point C & point 1,2,3.

I need this distance in C# code, currently my implementation is as below
Javascript that makes call to Google Map API resides in aspx.
I call this javascript from c# using below code

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ValError", "testDistance(lat1,long1,lat2,long2)", true);
```

My testDistance() method is written in javascript and gives me correct road distance.

**Problem:**
Getting the distance back in server side.
I am using hidden variable to save distance and get it back in server side but the issue is, that call to calculate distance has to be executed in a for loop in c# since there are various distances to be calculated and saved.

But i am unable to do so as hidden variable is set only at the first call and rest all distance values that are derived in subsequent calls are lost.

in javascript once i get distance i save it to hidden value like below.

```
var hiddist= document.getElementById("hidDistance");
hiddist.value=hiddist.value+distance;
```

Please help & suggest how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I know your struggles with this one.  I always use a jquery ajax post to call a webservice that I have in my C# project to pass data back to the codebehind from the clientside.  Please view this webpage this shows a good example of how to do this, but there are probably hundreds.  From what I have seen this is probably one of the better ways to handle this situation, this is also how I do all of my google maps pages that I create.

http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2012/01/jquery-ajax-examples-by-calling-aspnet.html

One other thing I would note is that I usually create classes in my codebehind and then join them all together.  (aka a class of multiple classes, maybe one class is a list of a class)  Then when I pass them  to the client side via something like. :

```
return parentClass.toArray();
```

Doing the above really allows you to handle/pass a lot more data in between the client and codebehind and also do so in a lot more uniform manner rather than passing around a string of a billion variables.  (One side note you can actually pass too much data between the client and codebehind doing it this way, which I have run into, but I wouldn't worry about that now)  HTH